# Method to return true or false if user is mod of a category in rials

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I want to write a simple mod method that checks a table to see if a user is a moderator of a category or not and return true of false.

Once the method is made i hope to write something like:

```
if current_user.mod? #or mod(current_user)?
  blah
else
  blah blah
end
```

here is what i have

```
def mod
 @user = current_user.id

 User.find(@user).anime_mods_relationships.where("anime_category_id = ?", params[:anime_id])
end
```

Users are associate as mods in a relationships table that holds the user id and category id.

This method just finds the relationship. I'm not sure how to change it to return true or false depending on if it can find the relationship or not. I was thinking maybe the exist? method might work but cant picture how to integrate it into the method.

I'm making a rails app to get better at rails but I haven't made a method from scratch (besides in tutorials). Whats the best way to go about this?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15855138/undefined-method-admin-for-nilnilclass

Comment: @SzilardMagyar I don't have a boolean mod column stored user table so user.mod? wont work. users can moderate multiple categories and categories can have multiple mods so I made a mods relationships table.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Clean way to do this

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  def mod_of?(anime_id)
    anime_mods_relationships.exists?(anime_category_id: anime_id)
  end
end
```

Then calling it in controller

```
if current_user.mod_of? params[:anime_id]
  # do something
else
  # do another thing
end
```

Comment: Looks great. But how does that method work? As in how does it know to check if the category id and user id pair up in the db?

Comment: I'm getting an error: undefined method `mod_of?' for #<User:0x007f827d2a40e8>

Comment: Strange that it's undefined. Could you please post your whole `user.rb` for reference?

Comment: I put the method in the anime_category_controller file. the the anime_category_controller create action is where i call `current_user.mod_of? params[:anime_id]`.

Comment: No, I mean you should put this method into `models/user.rb` file instead. It's model's logic.

Comment: Ok ill give it a shot. Didn't think it would be able to pickup the anime_id param in the user model

Comment: Oh no, I mean the `def mod_of?...` method is in `user.rb`, but the call `current_user.mod_of? params[:anime_id]` is in controller

Comment: Thanks. It works and is way better then what i had written up.